using only for loops find the bank accout with the lowest sum but not zero ( if no account balance is above 0 return an empty array
I'm working on an exercise that only allows us to use for loops for iterating. the question I'm working on is asking to return the bank account balance that has the lowest balance , so the minimum of all the accounts. and in case there are no accounts that have a balance above 0 return an empty array.
this is what I have so far I can't see what I've skipped, or overlooked any tips would be greatly appreciated!
//expected output 
min = { id: 2, name: "Morgan", balance: 3.0, deposits: [1100] }



const bankAccounts = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Susan",
    balance: 100.32,
    deposits: [150, 30, 221],
    withdrawals: [110, 70.68, 120],
  },
  { id: 2, name: "Morgan", balance: 3.0, deposits: [1100] },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Joshua",
    balance: 18456.57,
    deposits: [4000, 5000, 6000, 9200, 256.57],
    withdrawals: [1500, 1400, 1500, 1500],
  },
  { id: 4, name: "Candy", balance: 10.0 },
  { id: 5, name: "Phil", balance: 18.0, deposits: [100, 18], withdrawals: [100] },
];


function itsSomething(array){
  // Your code goes here...
  let min = 0;
  let minMin =[];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   if (array[0].balance > array[i].balance && array[i].balance >0 ){
     min = array[i]
   }else if ( array[i].balance > array[0].balance && array[0].balance > 0 ){
     min = array[0]
   }else if ( array[i].balance && array[0].balance < 0 ){
     min = []
   }
  } 
   return min
   
 }

console.log(itsSomething(bankAccounts))




Absent any other constraints, I might be inclined to sort() the array on the account balance.  Then you would just search forward through the sorted result to find the first with a positive balance.

@JohnBollinger  "Absent any other constraints" What about the constraint "exercise that only allows us to use for loops"  Furthermore using an O(n logn) algorithm for an O(n)  task isn't too clever most of the time ...

@derpirscher, "only allows us to use for loops for iterating".  The code already given uses if statements, which are not for loops.  I am inclined to suspect that there are other constraints, and if so, they should be edited into the question, but as currently posed, the question does not appear to preclude use of sort().

@JohnBollinger  The builtin sort oviously iterates the array, how would it sort otherways? And yes, obviously you need an if to do some comparisons ... And finally, this is obviously some sort of homework, to learn about using loops. And in such scenarios using built-in functions that do all the work for you (and with your suggestion even slower than it can be done) is seldomly the purpose ...

Eventhough the linked duplicate is for c++ the accepted answer provides easy to understand pseudocode for finding the minimum value in an array. You just have to add a condition to exclude accounts with balance <= 0

@derpirscher, clearly you can read the OP's mind, or clairvoyantly observe their homework instructions.  I hope you use your powers only for good.  For those of us without such gifts, the constraints on the OP's homework problem are unclear, and that information is relevant to the question.

@JohnBollinger no I cannot read minds, but I've seen enough of such questions here on stack overflow, on other forums and in real life in schools and universities to know how they are formulated. And even though it might not be mentioned with every question explicitly, uding built-in methods is prohibited most of the time. But that's not even the point. Using a sort algorithm to find the minimum of a collection is simply a bad habit. Especially if you need to iterate the sorted collection after all to check if the side condition is even met.

On each iteration, if the current element has a positive balance, compare it with the previous lowest balance. If the current balance is lower (or there was no previous account), then update the result.


const bankAccounts=[{id:1,name:"Susan",balance:100.32,deposits:[150,30,221],withdrawals:[110,70.68,120]},{id:2,name:"Morgan",balance:3,deposits:[1100]},{id:3,name:"Joshua",balance:18456.57,deposits:[4e3,5e3,6e3,9200,256.57],withdrawals:[1500,1400,1500,1500]},{id:4,name:"Candy",balance:10},{id:5,name:"Phil",balance:18,deposits:[100,18],withdrawals:[100]}];

function itsSomething(array){
  let res = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    if (array[i].balance > 0 && !(res.balance < array[i].balance))
      res = array[i];
  return res;
}

console.log(itsSomething(bankAccounts))




this is exactly what I was wondering how to do, I just didnt know how to explain it properly, comparing the old lowest balance to the next value and so on, thank you !

@JustinHawkins Happy to help.

// Online Javascript Editor for free
// Write, Edit and Run your Javascript code using JS Online Compiler
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Susan",
    balance: 0,
    deposits: [150, 30, 221],
    withdrawals: [110, 70.68, 120],
  },
  { id: 2, name: "Morgan", balance: 0, deposits: [1100] },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Joshua",
    balance: 0,
    deposits: [4000, 5000, 6000, 9200, 256.57],
    withdrawals: [1500, 1400, 1500, 1500],
  },
  { id: 4, name: "Candy", balance: 0 },
  { id: 5, name: "Phil", balance: 0, deposits: [100, 18], withdrawals: [100] },
];


function itsSomething(array){
  // Your code goes here...
  let min = {
     balance: 0,
  }
  let minMin =[];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(min.balance == 0){
            min = array[i]
        }else{
            min = array[i].balance < min.balance ? array[i] : min;    
        }
        
  } 
   return min.balance == 0 ? [] : min;
   
 }

console.log(itsSomething(bankAccounts))



const bankAccounts = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Susan",
    balance: 0,
    deposits: [150, 30, 221],
    withdrawals: [110, 70.68, 120],
  },
  { id: 2, name: "Morgan", balance: 0, deposits: [1100] },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Joshua",
    balance: 6,
    deposits: [4000, 5000, 6000, 9200, 256.57],
    withdrawals: [1500, 1400, 1500, 1500],
  },
  { id: 4, name: "Candy", balance: 0 },
  { id: 5, name: "Phil", balance: 200, deposits: [100, 18], withdrawals: [100] },
];


function itsSomething(array){
  // Your code goes here...
  let min = {
     balance: 0,
  }
  let minMin =[];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
     
        if(min.balance == 0){
            min = array[i]
        }else{
            
            min = (array[i].balance > 0) && array[i].balance < min.balance ? array[i] : min;    
        }
         
  } 
   return min.balance == 0 ? [] : min;
   
 }

console.log(itsSomething(bankAccounts))




you can break this line in [if else] CODE:  min = (array[i].balance > 0) && array[i].balance < min.balance ? array[i] : min;

If that worked for you please accept the answer and help the community.
